# Почему при импорте файла scss, в другой scss, он не хочет его читать или не видит?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

При импорте файла scss, в другой scss, он не хочет его читать, или не видит?

Путь я прописал правильно, потому что при клике на импорт, (зеленая стрелка), он перекидывает меня в файл App.scss.

Пока что не могу решить проблему. Приходится делать отдельные mixin в каждый файл и переменные тоже.

Спасибо!

[image: SASS файл]

Comment: я не понял если вы хотите использовать миксин в другом файле проста напишите `@include`

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Если я уберу миксин `@mixin border-header` с файла `Header.scss`, то выдает ошибку, потому что он не может прочитать `@import url('../../App.scss')`, а в` App.scss` находиться этот миксин

Comment: вы импортируете с начало `App.scss` в одном файле потом в другом также `index.scss` ? И еще они в одном уровне почему вы написали вот так `@import url('../../App.scss')`?Очень сложно по картинке понять что там происходит

Comment: Мне одному кажется странным импорт `App` в `index` и `index` в `App`? Наведите порядок в вашем коде, определите 1 исходный файл и в него подключайте все.